# Will this method prevent from xss

Tags: javascript, php, xss

friend found an interesting method, that should protect from xss injection.

```
<?php
$source = @$_GET['htmlsc'];
$source = mb_convert_encoding($source, 'UTF-7');
$source = htmlspecialchars($source); //defaults to ISO-8859-1
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8');
echo '<html><body><img src=' . $source . '></body></html>';
?>
```

This prevent from using characters such as = # < > ; "
I've tried many things, but none worked. The biggest problem is that I'm not allowed to use equal sign. Is there something I missed and XSS is possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't do anything to single quotes. Why not just encode the quotes with the `htmlspecialchars`, `ENT_QUOTES`?

Comment: That piece of code looks like it's from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3117935/404623

Comment: I've been given that code.